# Laravel Form input type="text" select data from another table on type type suggest existing data from the table and select

Tags: laravel-5.7

[How can i create a form like the one on linkedin. On form input type when i type is going to fect data from a database if not existis is going to create it and fetch d and store to another table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5uH7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

1. on form input type, immediately get result: This can be done by `AJAX`. Laravel support Vue which can do this easily:

1a. call a function in the `mounted()` part.

1b. the function call itself by putting `setTimeout(this.functionName,1000)` at the end.

1c. in the function, check if the text in the text box is changed. if yes, make a request by `axios.get('blablabla').then(response=>{//put the response into vue dataArrayName in data part});`

1d. the html template is auto-updated by `v-for="dataArrayName"`

2. looks like the search is done by comparing char by char from the beginning of the string to the data.
3. if you press `enter`, pass the search string to the controller, use some logic to determine whether it is needed to create row in database